# Airtable Scripting block - Batch copy a field to another field in same table (10,000 records)

Tags: airtable

I'm trying to copy one field to another field in the same table with 10,000 + records, in batches of 50 using the Scripting App.

What am I doing wrong in this code block? It only copies the first record. If I remove the await, it'll copy 15 records then stop.

```
let table = base.getTable('Merchants');
let view = table.getView('Grid view');
let query = await view.selectRecordsAsync();
let records = query.records;

updateLotsOfRecords(records);

async function updateLotsOfRecords(records) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < records.length) {
    const recordBatch = records.slice(i, i + 50);
    for (let record of recordBatch) {
      let sourceValue = record.getCellValue('Merchant');
      await table.updateRecordAsync(record, { 'LogoBase64': sourceValue });
    }
    i += 50;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use **updateRecordsAsync** function, not **updateRecordAsync**
When using single update function in loop, there is no sense to divide it into batches.
You exceed some limit of calls per second, that's why it stops.
For multiple updates, you need to use updateRecord**s**Async, like this

```
   while (recordsToWrite.length > 0) {
    await updates.updateRecordsAsync(recordsToWrite.slice(0, 50));
            recordsToWrite = recordsToWrite.slice(50);
        }
```

Data that you should pass to it, more complex. I learned JS for 3 months and still have difficulties understandins all these "arrays of arrays of objects, passed via object's property". But that's the key to unerstand JS.
It's quite hard to leave basic/pascal habits, with plenty of inserted FOR loops, and GOTO sometimes))

I think, you already found the answer for 2 months, so my answer may be useless, but when i write it here, maybe i understand it better for myself. And help to some beginners also.
For single write, you pass (record, Object), where object is {field:'Value}

For multiple, you should pass

```
Array of Objects, where

Object is {id:recordID, fields:{object2}} , where

object2 is array of obj3 [ {obj3},{obj3}, {obj3} ], where

obj3 is a { 'Name or ID of field': fieldvalue }
```

you script might be:

```
let query = await view.selectRecordsAsync();

let updates=query.records.map(rec=>{
```

Map method can be applied for arrays, and 'query.records' is array of records. Here
'rec' is loop variable inside this "arrowfunction"
now let's create obj3 , in our case  { 'Name or ID of field': fieldvalue }

```
 {'LogoBase64':rec.getCellValue('Merchant')}
```

wrap it into fields property

```
fields:{'LogoBase64':rec.getCellValue('Merchant')}
```

and add record id
wrapping as Object.
To avoid complex string with linebreaks, and to make object creation easier, we can do it with function:

```
{rec.id, fields:{'LogoBase64':rec.getCellValue('Merchant')}}

fuction myObj(rec){return {rec.id, fields:{'LogoBase64':rec.getCellValue('Merchant')}}

map(rec=>myObj(rec)) - can be written as map(myObj)
```

we need array of objects, and map method gets first array, doing something with each element and return other array, of results. like we need.
and now finally we get

```
let table = base.getTable('Merchants');
let view = table.getView('Grid view');
let query = await view.selectRecordsAsync();
function myObj(rec){return {'id':rec.id,'fields':{'Logobase64':rec.getCellValue('Merchant')}}};   
let updates=query.records.map(myObj);
  while (updates.length > 0) {
    await table.updateRecordsAsync(updates.slice(0, 50));
            updates = updates.slice(50); }
```